# How to use QCA library in Qt

Tags: qt, encryption, aes

I have used QCA (qca-2.0.1-mingw) library for encryption.
I have searched some code and write into the application. But it does not support the AES encryption standard.

e.g

```
QCA::supportedFeatures();
QCA::isSupported("aes128-cbc-pkcs7");
```

shows the o/p

("random", "md5", "sha1", "keystorelist") 
false

Why AES is not supported ?

---

**Thanx.. Frank and elmigranto**
now, i have download qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3 form [link](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) and also install the OpenSSl(Win32OpenSSL-1_0_0j.exe).then i build it by follows [this link](http://psi-im.org/wiki/Linux_Build_Instructions#Building_on_Windows_using_MinGW)

> configwin rd 
>   Configuring for release and debug, dynamic 
>   Wrote conf_win.pri
>   qmake 
>   C:\qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3>qmake
>   'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Also when i build the qca-ossl.pro file it shows o/p as:
c:\qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3\qca-ossl.pro:17: warning: Unable to find file for inclusion winlocal.prf

what to do next? pls help me guys..

Comment: Make sure you have the needed plugins (e.g. qca-ossl or somesuch - don't know which is needed for AES) and that they are found at runtime (by installing them to the Qt prefix or setting QT_PLUGIN_PATH).

Comment: It's probably `qca-ossl` is missing, as Frank noted. Also, be sure to install OpenSSL.

Comment: Anyone looked at the link lately? Its been trashed. http://psi-im.org/wiki/Linux_Build_Instructions#Building_on_Windows_using_MinGW Anyone have another please?